# Symfony2 always displays blank page in production

Tags: symfony

The application works in dev and test and a custom environment, but it does not work in production mode. I have tried all solutions I could find online, but couldn't solve the problem. The project is not so small and it stopped worked recently.

-Bundles are loaded fine in AppKernel

-Routing debug display all routes fine in production

-In app.php: $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);

-I have cleared cache and warmed it up. If I load without cache, it generated the prod cache fine.

-If I try to access any route, even an non-existing one, I get a blank page, so it looks like the routes are not being checked.

-No logs are written for production environment, also apache does not log anything. (logs work in other environments by monolog.)

I am using Symfony 2.4.5

Someone can help me here?

Comment: What does the `error.log` say?

Comment: No logs are created for production environment, not even apache shows any logs.

Comment: Did you modify the original `app.php` file?

Comment: I have not modified the app.php in any way, it is the same as original. (only tried changing debug to true/false)

Comment: If there's no logs it's hard to say what might went wrong. Maybe APC is the problem? Have you tried to clear APC or restart apache?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both, with and without APC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually points to a `FATAL` php error. But, as expected, you production server has `display_error` = `Off`.

It is hover weird that `apache` does not produce any errors in log file :-/ Inspect your `web` directory - maybe you'll find the `php_error` file there containing some details?

### EDIT:

Just remembered, thanks to the comments mentioning the `APC`. Similar thing used to happen to me beacause I had `APC` enabled in `app` but my dev box **did not have `APC` installed/enabled**

Comment: Thank you so much! I was a FATAL php error, I discovered a php error in the php_error.log and fixed it. It was an error in a service which is only loaded is production environment.

Answer (score 6):

did you give full permission to app/log and app/cache folders?

```
sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache app/logs
```

Comment: I have just tried this (locally) and it still gives blank pages.